# Mininet connection problem to ONOS controller

Tags: sdn, mininet, openflow, onos

When I execute the following command

```
sudo mn --controller remote,ip=127.0.0.1 --topo=single,4
```

ONOS shows the following Error

> Error while processing message from [127.0.0.1:54080
> DPID[00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01]]state WAIT_METER_FEATURES_REPLY
> io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderExpeption:
> org.projectfloodlight.openflow.exeptions.OFParseError: Wrong length:
> Expected=40(40), got=32

Kindly Help, How to resolve....?

Comment: You are using a newer version of openflow ? try something like 1.3 by running ```ovs-vsctl set bridge br protocols=OpenFlow13```

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem, most likely, related to the OpenFlow version. As @ikerfah said, try to define OpenFlow 1.3 in the mininet command, like:

> $ sudo mn --controller=remote,ip=127.0.0.1,port=6653 --switch=ovs,protocols=OpenFlow13 --topo=tree,depth=1,fanout=2